# easy file streaming program, what's wrong? how to improve?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

i am trying to learn C# so, i watch tutorials and follow them step by step, but i also like to add some small things to the programs they do in tutorials. this time i was watching thenewboston C# tutorial about file streaming, i want to create a text reading program which could both read byte-s and normal texts, so i created 3 buttons, 2 for choosing how the reader should show the text and 1 for opening file dialog, but something is wrong with byte reader when i choose that option it only show's zeros.

this is how my program looks like[image: my program]

this is how my text file looks like[image: my text file]

this is how my result looks like when choosing byte option[image]

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace sound
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    bool bytebuttonclicked = false;
    bool normalbuttonclicked = false;
    string text1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SoundPlayer My_JukeBox = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\WINDOWS\Media\tada.wav");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(OFD.FileName));
            if (normalbuttonclicked == true && bytebuttonclicked == false)
            {
                textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Dispose();
            }
            else if (bytebuttonclicked == true && normalbuttonclicked == false)
            {
                text1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[text1.Length];
                sr.BaseStream.Read(Buffer, 0, text1.Length);
                foreach (byte MyByte in Buffer)
                    textBox1.Text += MyByte.ToString("X") + " ";
                sr.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("choose one button");
            }
        }
        My_JukeBox.Play();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bytebuttonclicked = true;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        normalbuttonclicked = true;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
}
```

***So i don't understand why the program shows me zeros, what's wrong with my program and how can i improve it?
thank you.***

Comment: hmm i am not really good at working with debugger, i don't understand how it works, so i am debugging programs by myself.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the very first line and perform it step by step, checking that actual variables values equal to the expected. And as long as you find the place where they don't - you exactly would know where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `ReadToEnd` call reaches to the end of stream, so next `sr.BaseStream.Read` call tries to read ahead of end of the file hence all zeros. You can either:

- Convert already read `text1` to bytes instead of re-reading if you don't care about the data loss during encoding.

or

- Reset the position of the stream (not reader) by setting stream's (result of `File.OpenRead` operation) `Position` property.

or

- Re-open the stream.

Comment: i don't really get what text1 converting will change, can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

In response to ssg's answer and vato's comment.

ssg means that converting `text1` to a `Byte[]` instead of reading past the end of the file.

Replace these lines:

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[text1.Length];
sr.BaseStream.Read(Buffer, 0, text1.Length);
```

With this:

```
byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text1);
```

This will create a `byte[]` called `Buffer` that contains the `byte[]` of `text1`.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text1)` will convert `text1` to a `byte[]`.

Hope this helps!